# ERROR: 'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am facing issue while converting xml to html using xslt

dummy code as follow.

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslDoc = new StreamSource( xsltPath );
Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource( xmlPath );
oFileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream( htmlOutputPath );
htmlFile = oFileOutputStream;
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer( xslDoc );
transformer.transform( xmlDoc, new StreamResult( htmlFile ) );
```

**Error as Follow:**

```
ERROR:  'XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.'
```

my xml and xslt files are proper.If I use same code main method for testing its working fine but same code not parsing in project.
any idea???

Comment: I'm curious. What do you mean by "main method for testing its working but not parsing in project" ? Are you saying that the code is working with a sample test case but on with real data?

Comment: Well, the error indicates that your XML file is not proper. Check if you have malformed CDATA sections.

Comment: check your xml file again,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there might be some library conflict or version different in your environment. Please check all related libraries.

It seems that you have closed the stream while transformer is still doing the work. Please check that you have not closed any stream resources.